# Best way to design UI for java webapps

Tags: java, web-applications, user-interface, frameworks

I understand that there are lots of [web frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742223/what-is-the-most-commonly-used-java-web-framework/742993#742993) available for developing UI of java web applications. But I am not that good at designing UI; so I require a framework which gives me a UI designer as well. Is there any utility/tool/framework/eclipse-plugin which lets me design a good UI?

Answer (score 1):

Google plugin might help - http://code.google.com/eclipse/

Comment: Thanks. Can I integrate GWT with Struts2.0?